# Applications of relativistic, but non-gravitational, redshift

Tags: special-relativity, experimental-physics, redshift

I am trying to find real-world applications or experiment of the special relativity redshift, where any gravitational effect can be neglected. That is, when
$$
\frac{\lambda_\text{observed}}{\lambda_\text{source}} = \sqrt{\frac{1+\beta}{1-\beta}}\,,\qquad\beta = \frac{v}{c}\,.
$$
All the textbooks/lecture notes I looked at introduce the notion and find the above equation, but there is never any application. All the nice cases I can think of (exo-planets, cosmological expansion, etc) all need General Relativity to be explained. Is there experiment or discovery where everything can be explained only via Special Relativity (up to negligeable effects). By application I mean some interesting case that can be explained to students where SR was needed to make a new discovery, rather than e.g. a laser spectroscopy experiment to confirm the theory prediction.

I was thinking maybe some spectroscopy experiment to discover some element on a planet in the solar system where Special Relativity is enough, but I could not find anything concrete.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The relativistic Doppler shift is important for understanding [relativistic beaming](https://math.ucr.edu/home/baez/physics/Relativity/SR/Spaceship/spaceship.html), which explains (for example) the appearance of [relativistic jets](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Astrophysical_jet) that form around black holes.